# Cannot open output file ___.exe: Permission denied

Tags: c++, cygwin

Whenever I run a program using classes, I keep getting this error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot open output file Homework6.exe: Permission denied

I had to reset my computer last week and reinstall my IDE (CLion), along with Cygwin and the corresponding files. I followed along with my instructor's video of setting CLion up, but I'm still having issues. Is there a file I need to install again? This is the full error I get in CLion:

> C:\Users---.CLion2017.2\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build
>   C:\Users---\CLionProjects\CS1410\Homework6\cmake-build-debug --target Homework6 -- -j 2 Scanning dependencies of target Homework6 [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Homework6.dir/testArray.cpp.o [ 66%] Linking CXX executable Homework6.exe /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot open output file Homework6.exe: Permission denied
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Homework6.dir/build.make:121: Homework6.exe] Error 1
>
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/Homework6.dir/all] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/Homework6.dir/rule] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:118: Homework6] Error 2

Comment: Most likely the access permissions for the file are set incorrectly. Try running chmod 777 Homework6.exe.

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: In the terminal/shell. If you're running windows, search for cmd.exe, then `cd <your directory path>`, then `chmod 777 Homework6.exe`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. It seems that cygwin or ld just doesn't have the permissions needed to write the output file. It's not `Homework6.exe` that has the permission problems, unless it somehow is read-only

Comment: Cygwin is the issue. My IDE worked with it before, I added a few lines of code, now the code doesn't run within the IDE. But it's not the line of code that I added. I've had this issue across many projects now

Comment: Maybe the folder / path is wrong. Maybe your antivirus thinks your executable is a virus. If you have avast this is likely the case. Maybe you accidentally messed up the permissions on your folders somehow. Maybe the program is still running from the last time.

Comment: You will likely have to debug this yourself and come back after you have found the cause.

Comment: ***Is there a file I need to install again?*** I would say the answer to this is likely no.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and it was my anti-virus. BitDefender was blocking it. Turned on, I get the same error you do. Off, it works just fine. Then turning the anti-virus back on, same error as you get. It was my anti-virus so try turning all it's features off temporarily.